# Viewing data from database based on selected option in drop down menu

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, database

I'm creating a page which will allow an admin to select a user from a drop down list, which populates from a database. When the person is selected, the info associated with that person will then be viewed on the page. I already have a select statement which selects all the info and the drop down menu is populating correctly. However, I'm unsure on how to get that selected user's info to display on the page once selected. Would I need to do an entirely different select statement and query which checks which customer was selected? Or would I need to delve into the AJAX world?  If that's the case, how would I use AJAX and PHP together in the scope of this project?

```
<div id="view_form" class="view">
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="viewCustomer">Select Customer</label>
            <?php
                echo "<select name='selectCust' id='selectCust'>";
                echo "<option value=$name></option>";
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($custResult)){
                    $name = "{$row['fName']} {$row['lName']}";
                    $acct = $row['acctNum'];
                    echo "<option>$name</option>";
                }
                echo "</select>";
                echo "</fieldset>";
            ?>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Sidenote: It's usually best to wrap variables in quotes. I.e.: `echo "<option value=$name></option>";` to `echo "<option value=\"$name\"></option>";`

Comment: You *could* do it by having javascript automatically submit a form (loading a new page) when you change the dropdown, but you're better off using AJAX.

Comment: @Powerlord I've never mixed PHP and AJAX with each other.  Do you by chance have any references I could use or places I can look to learn how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely an AJAX situation. I'm not sure if you're using JQuery on this page, but that would help you a lot.

It would look something like this:

```
$("#selectCust").change(function(){
  var selected = $("#selectCust").val();
  $.ajax({
    url: "backEnd.php",
    data: {
      'selected': selected
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $( this ).addClass( "done" );
    }
  });
});
```

The database stuff would occur in `backEnd.php`.

Comment: I'm not understanding what the success function is doing.

Comment: The success function runs after the `backEnd.php` runs. Data will contain anything you echo in `backEnd` and can be used as a means to alert the user of success (or if your backEnd code doesn't run correctly it could alert users of that as well).

Comment: Ok, but that's still not answering how I would collect data from a database associated with the selected user.  For instance, how would I view the account number for a selected user?  As I said, I have never mixed AJAX with PHP, sorry, but your answer honestly doesn't help me.  The Ajax Documentation doesn't tell me anything when dealing with this.